# adding URI to laravel response

Tags: laravel, entity-relationship

I am building an API and I have few models which have a relationship with each other:

```
Asset
Location
User
```

I am able to get objects via api by accessing `/asset/5` or `/location/15`

This is all fine and good, now I have started to include some relations with it.. so if `asset 5` is related to `location 15`..  the return from `/asset/5` now includes (using WITH) the location info with it.

example:

```
/asset/5
```

```
{
    "id": 5,
--> "uri": http: //localhost/api/asset/5, <-- how do i generate/append this
     "name": null,
    "location": {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "jimUser",
-->     "uri": "http://localhost/api/location/5"  <-- how do i generate/append this
    }
}
```

(the URI is not part of my schema.. I want to have it added to the response.)

all of the location info is now returned with the asset. exactly what am looking for..

What I am trying to do is find a way to populate those URI fields with a link that is direct to that entity. so on the `/asset/` return that contains the related location info I want to be able to provide a link that goes directly to that location.

I am unable to find a way to generate the URI for either the main response (in this case it is asset) or for a relation (in this case it is location)

I am new to Laravel and am trying to basically mirror an application that has this same type of reponse.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

I tried working with `$request`, `$router` and many others.

Comment: I'm a little confused, is what you are looking for already in there? `location.uri` seems to be pointing to the location route?

Comment: My guess is that you want to change `localhost` by your `APP_URL`? using `config('app.url')`?

Comment: No, what I am looking for is not already in there.. the URI field is not returned. I want to find a way to generate that field and return it. I will edit my example. sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for your `uri` attribute and set it to be [appended](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) automatically to the JSON response:

```php
// Location.php

class Location
{
  protected $appends = ['uri'];

  ...

  public function getUriAttribute()
  {
    return '/api/locations/' . $this->id;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir!